# Базы данных для автотрекера

Tags: база-данных, проектирование, mysql

Необходимо спроектировать базу данных для системы слежения за автомобилями. На автомобиле стоит устройство слежения, которое отправляет свои координаты на сервер раз в N секунд.  Работаю с MySQL 5ой версии. Опуская ненужные подробности, в моей голове родилось два варианта:

1. Для хранения координат использовать одну таблицу с колонками:
   *[ID устройства(primary key)], [Долгота], [Широта], [Дата_Время]*
   Получается, что в одной таблице хранятся все треки для всех устройств.
2. Использовать отдельную таблицу для каждого трекаустройства и хранить в базе таблицу:
   *[ID устройства(primary key)], [Имя таблицы трека]*
   Запросы получаются сложнее, но каждый трек лежит в БД отдельно.

Внимание вопрос: какой вариант использовать лучше и почему? Или оба варианта не тру и есть вариант номер три?

Comment: ИМХО, варианта №1 вполне хватит

Comment: трек это за какое время?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Две таблицы. Первая - последние N точек для активных в данный момент устройств, где N - достаточное число для отображения логического маршрута(для такси - один заказ). Вторая - все точки для всех устройств. При отключении устройства оно пропадает из первой таблицы.
Для каждого устройства создавать таблицу не надо.

Comment: А смысл тягать данные из одной таблицы в другую? Если уже есть *все* точки, то среди них есть и N последних точек. Индекс только не забыть для их выбора.

Comment: Смысл в том, чтобы вычищать неактивные устройства, как не представляющие интереса для трекера. Это существенно сэкономит время при запросе текущего положения всех авто, которые сейчас в пути.

Иногда один автомобиль может начать и закончить маршрут, пока другой еще едет. В моем варианте он в окончательную выборку уже не попадет.

Comment: Мне нравится что при таком подходе будет активная таблица, допустим за последние 24 часа, и сразу архив, мне это кажется удобным. Архив можно и пережать и почистить, раз в пол года допустим. А основная нагрузка ляжет на активную таблицу. Хотя при реализации придется немного заморочиться кому и из какой таблицы данные доставать при запросе, и в какой момент чистить активную таблицу, если устройство онлайн 24х7.

Comment: Он и в моем варианте в выборку не попадет. Горизонтальный шардинг никогда не сделает работу с запросами _удобнее_ и не изменит их семантику.

Вопрос в том, что именно «не представляет интереса» для трекера. Тут задачу нужно знать.

Comment: 24х7 реального, то есть ровного по нагрузке круглые сутки, у вас не будет, если только вы не мониторите автомобили во всемирном масштабе :) поэтому будете переливать и паковать таблицы раз в сутки в пять утра, например.

А если трафик в таблицу прет постоянно, то тут уже возможны более тонкие варианты. Например, писать в две таблицы сразу, регулярно пересоздавая «оперативную», а select-ы по большим объемам (отчеты строить, например) направить на slave…

Comment: Еще вопрос, нужна ли вам транзакционность, и на каком уровне изоляции (тогда spatial для mysql отпадает). Ну и так далее.

Короче, нужно хорошо знать, какие запросы будут к базе делаться и как часто.

Answer (score 7):

Отдельные таблицы — ни в коем случае. Не нарушайте смысл SQL :)
Зачем вам отдельные таблицы для однотипных объектов?

Вот когда записей будут многие миллионы, можно будет подумать о шардинге и разбить на несколько таблиц, чтобы разместить данные по разным серверам; а пока пусть все в одной таблице хранится.

Далее, чтобы спроектировать таблицу, нужно представлять, какие запросы у вас к ней будут. Тут вам лучше знать, но для начала понятно, что:

- Отдельной сущностью, уникальной в задаче, является пара ( объект, время ). Не может быть две записи в одно время для одного автомобиля. Это и будет primary key.
- Для каждого объекта нам нужен список координат не абы как, а упорядоченный в хронологическом порядке, и частенько не весь, а в интервале «от и до». Тут спасибо MySQL, индекс для primary key покрывает эту потребность
- Координаты нам, вероятно, понадобятся для запросов вида «в каком квадрате находятся какие автомобили». Здесь уже точно нужно знать, какие именно запросы будут… Но пока, раз MySQL предоставляет функции OpenGIS, то почему бы ими не воспользоваться, и не набросить на координаты spatial индекс? (правда, для этого тип таблицы должен быть только MyISAM).

Получается так:

```
CREATE TABLE tracks
(
  id        INTEGER     NOT NULL,
  tm        TIMESTAMP   NOT NULL,
  coords    POINT       NOT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (id, tm),
  SPATIAL INDEX(coords)
) ENGINE = MyISAM;
```

Данные в такую таблицу вставляются вот так:

```
INSERT INTO tracks VALUES
(1, '2011-09-02 12:00:00', POINT(50.456257,30.511237)),
(1, '2011-09-02 12:00:01', POINT(50.456230,30.511425)),
(1, '2011-09-02 12:00:02', POINT(50.456244,30.510902));
```

И затем с ними можно делать много вкусного, например, проверить, какие автомобили находились в заданном квадрате в определенное время:

```
SELECT id
  FROM tracks
  WHERE tm < (NOW() - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE)
    AND MBRWithin(
        coords,
        GeomFromText('Polygon((50.456736 30.510540, 50.455690 30.510540, 50.455690 30.513295, 50.456736 30.513295, 50.456736 30.510540))')
        ) = 1;
```

Ну а там уже надо брать реальные запросы и эксплейнить. Кстати, устройство слежения что, не отдает скорость и направление движения? Тоже стоит их в базу записывать, чтобы потом можно было удалить левые точки, когда GPS лагает.

Comment: Многие миллионы записей появятся подозритеольно быстро.  
1 маршрут - 100-1000 точек  
1 день - 1-10 маршрутов  
Примерно за треть года(а то и значительно раньше) наберется первый миллион всего сотней машин.   
Насчет поинта - идея хорошая, но у постгреса она реализована лучше, вроде как.

Comment: На «миллионы» надо смотреть не по их количеству, а по железу, тянет или нет.

PostGIS, конечно, намного круче, но в вопросе тег стоит — mysql.

Comment: Есть смысл использовать PostgreSQL вместо MySQL для решения данной задачи?

Comment: А у вас будет активная работа с географией?

Comment: В каком плане активная работа с географией? Визуализацию трека я планирую делать при помощи YandexMap API, если вы об этом. Какая-то иная обработка треков на данный момент не планируется, если и буду разрабатывать дополнительные сервисы, помимо обычной визуализации трека за энный промежуток времени, то только в далеком будущем.

Comment: Активная в том смысле, будут ли хитрые географические запросы к базе, ну там «выбрать объекты в радиусе 50 км от заданной точки». Правда, для такого запроса и OpenGIS неудобен, тогда лучше координаты из широты-долготы в 3D переводить.

А раз их нет, то postgres+postgis во всей своей красоте вам не понадобится.

Answer (score 0):

Если вам только обновлять надо координаты и не надо вести историю для каждого, то лучше пользоваться первым вариантом. Если нужна история, то вторым, но базу захламите быстро, если устройств много. Вот от этого и пляшите.